# Unexpected Indent Error - trying to tweak someone else code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here the code. I don't know python and trying to tweak someone else code

I am trying to write what is printed in for loop

```
        for poke in visible:
        other = LatLng.from_degrees(poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude)
        diff = other - origin
        # print(diff)
        difflat = diff.lat().degrees
        difflng = diff.lng().degrees
        direction = (('N' if difflat >= 0 else 'S') if abs(difflat) > 1e-4 else '')  + (('E' if difflng >= 0 else 'W') if abs(difflng) > 1e-4 else '')

        print("(%s) %s is visible at (%s, %s) for %s seconds (%sm %s from you)" % (poke.pokemon.PokemonId, pokemons[poke.pokemon.PokemonId - 1]['Name'], poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude, poke.TimeTillHiddenMs / 1000, int(origin.get_distance(other).radians * 6366468.241830914), direction))

    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:       
        myfile.write("(%s) %s is visible at (%s, %s) for %s seconds (%sm %s from you)" % (poke.pokemon.PokemonId, pokemons[poke.pokemon.PokemonId - 1]['Name'], poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude, poke.TimeTillHiddenMs / 1000, int(origin.get_distance(other).radians * 6366468.241830914), direction))
        myfile.write("\n")
        myfile.flush()
```

Comment: Is this what the code actually looks like?

Comment: no this is just a part of it. but the question simple. trying to write in a file what is printed above

Comment: Either the initial for loop should not be indented or its body needs additional indent.  Without context, impossible to tell.  You should add the complete error message, including traceback.

Comment: the fore loop doesn't line up.. please re indent

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Indentation is extremely important in Python. Indentation serves the same purpose as `{...}` in other languages. So as it is now your `for` loop is the equivalent of `for poke in visible{}` in other languages. Then your `with` is possibly outdented to far if it's not part of another indented block.

Comment: "trying to write in a file what is printed above" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there is no brackets to define blocks. It is done with whitespace. So if you have lines with a different amount of indentation than other lines, or you are missing indentation where there is supposed to be some, then the interpreter will raise an IndentationError.

Assuming your code was pasted properly, you have a for loop with no content under it (because it is not properly indented). It should look like this:

```
for poke in visible:
    other = LatLng.from_degrees(poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude)
    diff = other - origin
    # print(diff)
    difflat = diff.lat().degrees
    difflng = diff.lng().degrees
    direction = (('N' if difflat >= 0 else 'S') if abs(difflat) > 1e-4 else '')  + (('E' if difflng >= 0 else 'W') if abs(difflng) > 1e-4 else '')

    print("(%s) %s is visible at (%s, %s) for %s seconds (%sm %s from you)" % (poke.pokemon.PokemonId, pokemons[poke.pokemon.PokemonId - 1]['Name'], poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude, poke.TimeTillHiddenMs / 1000, int(origin.get_distance(other).radians * 6366468.241830914), direction))

with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:       
    myfile.write("(%s) %s is visible at (%s, %s) for %s seconds (%sm %s from you)" % (poke.pokemon.PokemonId, pokemons[poke.pokemon.PokemonId - 1]['Name'], poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude, poke.TimeTillHiddenMs / 1000, int(origin.get_distance(other).radians * 6366468.241830914), direction))
    myfile.write("\n")
    myfile.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the start - Where it has the for statement. In python, anything requiring a colon at the end MUST be indented.

The easiest way is to go through each line in the for statement and press the TAB key. This will indent the code for you.  Hope it helps!

Id also watch or read a basic tutorial of python that shows how indentation works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm hopefully assuming you've got more code than what you have shown all of us (it's actually quite hard to answer these questions without more code sometimes), then if you have already declared all of your variables and what not behind the scenes then all you should have to do is fix the indentation like so:

```
for poke in visible:
    other = LatLng.from_degrees(poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude)
    diff = other - origin
    # print(diff)
    difflat = diff.lat().degrees
    difflng = diff.lng().degrees
    direction = (('N' if difflat >= 0 else 'S') if abs(difflat) > 1e-4    
    else '')  + (('E' if difflng >= 0 else 'W') if abs(difflng) > 1e-4 
    else '')
    print("(%s) %s is visible at (%s, %s) for %s seconds (%sm %s from 
    you)" % (poke.pokemon.PokemonId, pokemons[poke.pokemon.PokemonId - 
    1]['Name'], poke.Latitude, poke.Longitude, poke.TimeTillHiddenMs / 
    1000, int(origin.get_distance(other).radians * 6366468.241830914), 
    direction))

    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:       
        myfile.write("(%s) %s is visible at (%s, %s) for %s seconds    
        (%sm %s from you)" % (poke.pokemon.PokemonId, 
        pokemons[poke.pokemon.PokemonId - 1]['Name'], poke.Latitude, 
        poke.Longitude, poke.TimeTillHiddenMs / 1000, 
        int(origin.get_distance(other).radians * 6366468.241830914), 
        direction))
        myfile.write("\n")
        myfile.flush()
```

If you'r still pretty new to python then probably go give [this](http://pdf.th7.cn/down/files/1508/Learning%20Python,%205th%20Edition.pdf) a read, and if you're still not sure then go ahead and give [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers) one a read as well. I've found both pretty helpful.